# How to put DatetimePicker In gridview cell in wpf using C#?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, datetimepicker

How to place a datetime picker in a gridview cell,i ham having a gridview ,in the last column i want to place the datetime picker,how to insert the picker into the gridview cell in wpf

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) to put any control inside a cell in the `DataGrid`. Here is minimal example using a `DatePicker` control. It assumes that the `DataContext` has a property named `Items` which is a collection of objects having a property named `Date`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When you set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` you will have to declare all your columns yourself by adding them to the `DataGrid.Columns` collection property and besides using `DataGridTemplateColumn` you can use `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, `DataGridHyperlinkColumn`, `DataGridTextColumn` and `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Data" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Data}" Header="Data prevista fine" IsReadOnly="False">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Data,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </DatePicker>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data,Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In this way you have the ability to edit the data through the DataPiker and format the date that you have binded with the format you prefer